# OpenSCAD: How to avoid extra grouping in CSG tree

Tags: openscad, csg

I want to write a module that can optionally combine its children as either a union or a difference.

```
module u_or_d(option="d") {
    if (option == "d") {
        difference() children();
    } else {
        union() children();
    }
}

module thing(option) {
    u_or_d(option) {
        cube(10, center=true);
        cylinder(h=20, d=5, center=true);
    }
}

translate([-15, 0, 0]) thing("d");
translate([ 15, 0, 0]) thing("u");
```

I was surprised that this doesn't work.  Both instances of thing appear to create a union of the cube and the cylinder.

The CSG Tree Dump shows the problem.  Here's the relevant excerpt:

```
difference() {
  group() {
    cube(size = [10, 10, 10], center = true);
    cylinder($fn = 0, $fa = 12, $fs = 2, h = 20, r1 = 2.5, r2 = 2.5, center = true);
  }
}
```

The children are wrapped in a group, so the `difference()` effectively has only one child, which happens to be an implicit union of the wrapped children.

Is there a way to invoke `children()` that avoids this unwanted grouping?  If not, is there another way for a module to allow the invoker to select how the module combines its children?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
module u_or_d(option="d") {
    if (option == "d" && $children > 1) {
        difference() {
            children([0]);
            children([1:$children-1]);
        }
    } else {
        union() children();
    }
}
```

You still get a group wrapped around each invocation of children, but at least we can make two groups.